# Hide column of sql results and and show below table onClick

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, show-hide

I have a table that displays SQL results, however I would like the table to display certain results, and display more upon a click, below the table in a div tag. So far I have this code that displays,'title' and 'email' and the 3rd column which will trigger a JS function and display 'details' in a div tag... How do I use JavaScript to display the specific details and hide those details when a second row details is clicked and replace the first 1?

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#" onClick="moreDetails();">More details...</a></td>
    </tr>
```

EDITED:
After a comment I received, here is my entire code of the table with the div element with the id "details"

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Investment Title</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Details</strong></td>
    </tr>

<?php

    // Start looping table row
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#" onClick="viewInvestor();">More details...</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    // Exit looping and close connection
}
    mysql_close();
?>
    <tr>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="detail"></div>
```

Comment: You're trying to wear your socks after you already put on your shoes: start by describing the HTML structure of the table that you want and which columns/divs should be hidden/visible upon which scenario. after you realize that, it'll be easier to start with the PHP code that generates the HTML/JS

Comment: thanks, i've tried editing the code accodingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you want to do but you can try something like this. I hope this helps

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Investment Title</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
        <td><a href='#' id='show_details'>More Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
        <td id='details'><?php echo $rows['details'];?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript - JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#details').hide(); //on ready hide the td details

    $('#show_details').click(function()
    {
        $('#details').show();
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

**YOU MEAN LIKE THIS**  **[SEE MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/57/)**

Comment: I was going to suggest something like this myself (+1 for beating me to it) - create the data with the HTML and simply hide it. Then click on the link to display it.

Comment: this wasn't exactly what i was hoping for, but I do get the idea... I'll try twist things around. Thank you @Þaw

Comment: @Felix I've added a fiddle in my answer see my fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery:

HTML

```
<td id='details'>The details are in here...</td>
<td id='details1'>The other details are in here...</td>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('details').style.display = 'table-cell';
document.getElementById('details1').style.display = 'none';
```